# Running a bat file from another

Tags: batch-file

this is the structure of a batch file

```
SET CURDATE=%date%
REM run some code bellow
.....
.....
.....
.....
"C:\CADMAC2k\SYS\CADMAC.exe"
```

this batch file reads the current date, does some modifications and then starts cadmac.exe (a cad program).

this batch file needs to be run as administrator right, but cadmac.exe should be run as current logged-in account.

when I right click this batch file and select **run as administrator**, cadmac.exe is run with admin rights too.

Is there any way to make cadmac.exe run with current user rights (logged in account) not administrator rights?

any kind of advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If there are specific commands in your batch file that need to be run as Administrator you can use the **[runas](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx)** command.

Then, you can start the batch file as the logged-in user. runas prompts for Administrator credentials when necessary.

Comment: Since this batch file is going to run in a windows domain from client PCs, I can't pass the admin password to domain users.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Run AS for exe.
Here is possible solution
[Running .exe's with Run As in a .bat file](http://www.techimo.com/forum/technical-support/90867-running-exes-run-bat-file.html)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried **runas /user:Kotobuki\K_Hb_2 "C:\CADMAC2k\SYS\CADMAC.exe"** but I was asked for password. any other advice?   thanks

Comment: I think you doesn't read solution provided above link, you have to provide password, There are tools which can encrypt password list of them are available http://www.commandline.co.uk/sanur/ here, hope this will help you.

Comment: sorry for not being clear enough. I read the link. This is what I found: **Sanur 'pipes' a password into the Windows 2000/XP/2003 Runas utility ** unfortunately most of our PCs run on windows 7 and 8. I'm looking for an alternative solution.

Comment: there is tool psexec you can try this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553